# Passing structure to a template function in C++

Tags: c++, function, templates

This is what i want to achieve,

1. I want to pass structure as an argument to a function, which will return character pointer
2. Everytime i will pass different structure as argument, which has distinct name and member variables of different types
3. The function has to identify the structure and its member variables, get the value of the member variable and concatenate it as a single string and return.

Please suggest....

am confused with template function and RTTI.....

Comment: Do the structs all differ in the member names or not? Do they all have only 2 members? Without much more information there is no way to do this generically, IMHO.

Comment: Yes member names are different. It has 2 to 6 member variables in different structures.

Answer (score 3):

You could look into [Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html), in particular [BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html).

Answer (score 1):

The first suggestion that crosses my mind is: redesign!

If you really want to do it like you say and don't know the names of the fields, I don't think a template will do you any good.  I'd suggest using the preprocessor:

```
#define UGLY(str, int_field, char_field) whatever_you_want_to_do_with_them
```

and then you'd call:

```
a some_a;
b some_b;

UGLY(some_a, x, y);
UGLY(some_b, b, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no particularly nice way to iterate over class members. One approach I've used is to store the values in a tuple, and provide named accessors if required:

```
struct a {
    std::tuple<int, char*> stuff;
    int  & x() {return std::get<0>(stuff);}
    char & y() {return std::get<1>(stuff);}
};
```

In the future (next year, perhaps?) we should get type deduction for function return types (as we already have for lambdas), which will remove error-prone type specifier in each accessor.

You can then use variadic template functions to iterate over the tuples.

Comment: Is there a proposed draft somewhere about function return type deduction?

Comment: @fish: I think so; but I don't have a link to hand.

Comment: There is a bug in you example there, you declare the 2nd tuple parameter as char* but then return a reference to to a char, you maybe want char*& instead. You did say it was error prone :)

You could probably use :-

struct a {
    std::tuple<int, char*> stuff;
    decltype(std::get<0>(stuff)) & x() {return std::get<0>(stuff);}
    decltype(std::get<1>(stuff)) & y() {return std::get<1>(stuff);}
};

instead, less error prone but more verbose... (Ugh no way to format this that I can see)

Comment: @jcoder: Well spotted. I noticed, but decided to leave it in as a demonstration that it is error-prone (as described in the next paragraph). The compiler should spot the mistake, so it's not too serious. `decltype` is just as error-prone, since you're duplicating the tuple index; so I think this is the best we can do until we get type deduction.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't represent your structs (Which have same memeber types, but different names) as tuples?. IMHO if you want to treat this set of structs in the same manner, having different names is counterproductive:

```
template<typename...Ts>
void f(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The structs are all having different names and different/distinct member types.

Comment: I meant that, for example, `struct A` has the same meber types as `struct B`, but with different names. Note that I suggest you a tuple, to achieve your comment about structs with different number of members.